# Stetho - Android Studio Initialization

Tags: android, android-studio, stetho

I am having trouble trying to use Stetho, I've tried to search and follow the steps provided by others but, it seems none of them highlight my problem. Below is what is in my needed files for Stetho utilization.

My problem is it cannot identify the method "initialize" I've tried other ways of implementing the method through the suggestion of other users but, I still meet the same error

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }
```

in my Stetho Application Class

```
 import android.app.Application;

 public class Stetho extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);


    }
 }
```

declared in my Manifest

```
    <application
    android:name=".Stetho"
       android:allowBackup="true"
```

I thought the problem is, I don't actually have the library implemented correctly, but I am not sure.

Comment: naming confict. choose a different name for your class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably getting name conflicts because your App class is named Stetho as well. Rename your `App` class on the .java and .manifest files. Import the `Stetho` package into your app class.

Your app class should look something like this:

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.stetho.Stetho;

public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);

    }
}
```

And your manifest like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true" />
```

Comment: Ah yes, I had a name conflict, thank you very much! It's working as intended now.